# OST in Naruto Shippuden

Tags: naruto, music

What is the ost playing at 1:54-3:53 in episode 456 of Naruto Shippuden?
The same song can also be heard in episode 368 at 1:31-2:33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an unreleased track. It doesn't show up in any of the [soundtrack albums listed on the Wikia](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Music).

There are some [unofficial imperfect versions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTVgPZtUlKk) floating around on YouTube.